# Why StopIteretion error for calling next function after displaying list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, generator

```
def hundred_numbers():
  i=0
  while i<100:
    yield i
    i=i+1

print(hundred_numbers())
g=hundred_numbers()
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(list(h))
print(next(g))
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in 
    print(next(g))
StopIteration

Comment: If you've exhausted your generator object using `list`, then `i` won't enter the loop, and won't yield anything.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've exhausted your generator object and there is nothing left for it to yield to your program.

```
def hundred_numbers():
    i=0
    while i<100:
        yield i
        i=i+1
g=hundred_numbers()
[next(g) for _ in range(10)] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[next(g) for _ in range(10)] # [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

See a pattern? Now let's grab the rest, i.e. 20-99

```
items = list(g)  # Could have done [next(g) for _ in range(20,100)]
```

items will now be the remaining values 20 through 99. So what happens the next time? It can't enter the `while` loop, so there is nothing to yield. This can be seen if you do: `list(g)` again. This would result in an empty list since there is nothing to grab.